# Spring with Hibernate JPA using Virtual database columns not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

I have a scenario like where i have an Entity with variable (say x) which points to Virtual column in DB. I used this variable x just to project some data onto UI or so and don't want that to be inserted or updated when Iam updating or creating the entity  object.

For this to be achieved i have introduced insertable and updatable to be false as shown below

```
  @Column(name = "VIRTUAL_COLUMN_NAME_IN_DB", length = 4000, updatable = false, insertable = false)
  private String x;
```

I have introduced associated getters and setters as well.

With the annotations i introduced, i expected variable x to be not included part of insert or update opeartions

But, its not the case and i see it coming up in insert and update operations, which inturn causing me have a DB error below

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [99999]; error code [54017]; ORA-54017: UPDATE operation disallowed on virtual columns
; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: ORA-54017: UPDATE operation disallowed on virtual columns
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:651)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:105)
```

Please let me know how to use virtual columns in Spring based application with Hibernate JPA

Comment: Tried to have the column annotated with @Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS). But, no luck with this either

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I tried on H2 computed columns, but with updatable=false and insertable=false computed column is never mentioned in updates and inserts.

Comment: I am using Oracle DB. Can you please let me know the version of Hibernate JPA you are using ?

Comment: 9 years later: remove the setter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the @Transient annotation? It is supposed to be exactly for that: "This annotation specifies that the property or field is not persistent. It is used to annotate a property or field of an entity class, mapped superclass, or embeddable class."

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html

Comment: If I use this, then it doesn't even read this value from the DB. Is their any way by which we can read but not write?